# Elasticsearch: 'x_content_parse_exception' [template] unknown field [lifecycle]

Tags: elasticsearch, lifecycle, data-stream

I have elk stack deployed from [deviantony/docker-elk](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk) version 8.9 .

And i'm trying to create lifecycle with retention policy for my datastream as mentioned in [official documentetion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/tutorial-manage-new-data-stream.html)

```
PUT _index_template/my-index-template
{
  "index_patterns": ["my-data-stream*"],
  "data_stream": { },
  "priority": 500,
  "template": {
    "lifecycle": {
      "data_retention": "7d"
    }
  },
  "_meta": {
    "description": "Template with data stream lifecycle"
  }
}
```

but i got error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
        "reason": "[6:5] [template] unknown field [lifecycle]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
    "reason": "[6:18] [index_template] failed to parse field [template]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
      "reason": "[6:5] [template] unknown field [lifecycle]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from Elastic team member that for now it is experimental feature and extra steps should be performed for it to work.
Link to answer:  https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-x-content-parse-exception-template-unknown-field-lifecycle/340009/3